# How to identify SOAP api version used in Salesforce by external application

Tags: soap-api, integration

We have a salesfore org where an external application is using an enterprise wsdl and consumes data from Salesforce. Currently we have been told by salesforce that we are using an old version of soap api which is no longer supported. The below link explains this issue.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250959&type=1&language=en_US
We want to find out the exact api version used by the external application. The event logs does not provide it and the WSDL files only have a comment on the api version which has been deleted by external developers. How can we identify the exact version of soap api used by the external application?
Buyan

Comment: Do you have the original WSDL? Do you see a URL like `https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/...` anywhere in the file? The version should be part of the URL.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for your reply. There is no url like this on the WSDL. Any other thoughts?

Comment: At the end of the WSDL, there should be a "service" tag, that contains a "port" tag, which contains a "soap:address". What's the address located there? If it's not there, where are you getting the server connection from? The URL should be the key.